# How to check if a timer is still running or not?

Tags: android, timer

I try to send sms in service.If the sms is not sent means I restart the service after some time, for that I Using the timer.If the sms sent means I want to stop the timer,for stop the timer I use timer.cancel(); before that I've to check the timer is running or not.how to check it?.

```
             int resultCode = getResultCode();
                 switch (resultCode) 
                 {
                case Activity.RESULT_OK:                 
                             timer.cancel();//Here I want to check timer running or not
                 break;

                 case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_GENERIC_FAILURE:  
                     timer_run();
                 break;

                 case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_NO_SERVICE:     
                     timer_run();
                 break;

                 case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_NULL_PDU:        
                      timer_run();
                  break;

                 case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_RADIO_OFF:        
                     timer_run();
                  break;

                 }
```

Timer Schedule function

```
    public void timer_run(){        

    TimerTask hourlyTask = new TimerTask () {
        @Override
        public void run () {
             Intent myIntent = new Intent(Myservice.this,Myservice.class); 
             startService(myIntent);


        }
    };
     timer.schedule (hourlyTask, 0l, 500*5*5);
   }
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is no need to check if the timer is running if all you want to do is [`cancel()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TimerTask.html#cancel%28%29) it (This is true for both the [`Timer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html#cancel%28%29) and the [`TimerTask`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TimerTask.html#cancel%28%29)).

The documentation states that

> This method may be called repeatedly;
>   the second and subsequent calls have no effect.

Comment: I am getting the this if i call `cancel()` on an already cancelled `Timer` object. - `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Timer already cancelled.`

Answer (score -2):

why you don't use Try .... and printStackTrace to do not get the crash message
java.lang.IllegalStateException : Timer already cancelled

simply use :

```
try {
            timer.cancel();
        } catch (Exception r) {
            r.printStackTrace();
        }
```